# Laravel AJAX: insert with loop (looping DB table row)

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm new in Laravel and Ajax, and I have working code (see below).

I have 2 tables, criteria and rating.

I want to query first the table named:criteria like `(select * from criteria where level = 1)`,
then using the result, I want to save multiple rows in "ratings" using some field of query result  + some input variable from user.

Like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < criteria-result.length; i++) {
   $addItem= New Rating;
   $addItem->empname = $request->empname; //this is from user this is a repeating value
   $addItem->criteria = criteria-result[i].(criteria)
}
```

Existing Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'generate-rating-criteria',
data: {
'employee_name':  $("#emp_name").text(),
},
success: function()
{
    swal("Saved", "Ok", "success")
},
error: function(xhr, status, error)
{

    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
     alert(err.Message);
}
});
```

Existing Controller:

```
 $addItem= New Rating;
 $addItem->employee_name =  $request->employee_name;
 $addItem->save();
```

Comment: Does any error occurs?

Comment: with the Existing Controller and  Ajax no errors yet, but that's incomplete code. what I want to accomplish is to loop with a query result and use the value of rows.

Comment: So please add you query in the question. How can you retrieve the result.

Comment: Hi @AmitSenjaliya thanks for replying very quick.
Acutally I don't know yet how to do it in laravel but its like this:

 $criteria= DB::table('criteria') where (level = 1)
then using the result
I want to save the values per row in the rating table. like in the example of my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a count() method instead of length.

```
$criteria = DB::table('criteria')->where('level', 1)->get();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($criteria); $i++) {
    $addItem= New Rating;
    $addItem->empname = $request->empname;
    $addItem->criteria = $criteria[$i]->criteria; /* if criteria column exist in the rating table. */
    $addItem->save();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Amit thank you I will try this when I got home. :)

Comment: I got error
'message: "Use of undefined constant criteria - assumed 'criteria ' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)"
exception: "ErrorException"'

Comment: @user12795647 you have table `criteria` in your database?

Comment: @user12795647 Also which line you have error occur?

Comment: oh you still there.. :) ye I have

Comment: @user12795647 so i think `$criteria[$i]->criteria;` column not exists in the rating table/

Comment: Hi again @Amit, my bad, I missed the '$' in criteria. thank you! all good now.